# Add new child objects to existing object in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, javascript-objects

I am trying to update through useState a child object with an additional object.  I created an example to make this more clear :

https://codesandbox.io/s/affectionate-wescoff-u01x0?file=/src/App.js

The example object looks like :

```
{
  "id": 123,
  "books": {
    "book": {}
  }
}
```

When I push more data in I want it to look like this :

```
{
  "id": 123,
  "books": {
     "book": {
      "name": "Sirens of Titan",
      "author": "Kurt Vonnegut"
      },
     "book": {
      "name": "The Hobbit",
      "author": "J.R.R. Tolkein"
    }
  }
}
```

At this stage I have it pretty messed up and it looks like :

```
{
   "id":123,
   "books":[
      {
         "0":{
            "book":{
               
            },
            "sampleData1":{
               "book":{
                  "name":"Sirens of Titan",
                  "author":"Kurt Vonnegut"
               }
            }
         },
         "sampleData2":{
            "book":{
               "name":"The Hobbit",
               "author":"J.R.R. Tolkein"
            }
         }
      }
   ]
}
```

This is the way I set that broken object :

```
  const [main, setMain] = useState(library);

  function addNestedObj() {
    setMain({ ...main, books: [{ ...main.books, sampleData1 }] });
  }
```

Comment: Why not use the books value as an array instead of an object ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `books` property of your `library` object was an object, not an array. This might have been necessary but I guessed that it isn't since your book objects already have a `name` property, so they don't need a separate key.

With that change, you can modify your `setMain` function to add the `book` property of the `sampleData` to the `books` property of your state:

```js
setMain({ ...main, books: [...main.books, sampleData1.book] });
```

I've added these changes in a fork of your CodeSandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/modest-fog-byegh?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Ah, I was trying to make a simple example of my project and kind of messed it up.  What you shared in your sandbox totally helped me get through this though.  Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Just take the destructuring a stage further:

```
setMain({...main, kids: [...main.kids, secondObj]})
```

Comment: Thanks for your response but I am still not able to get it to work. I updated my question and sandbox with a better example to hopefully work this out.  Can you show me what you are talking about there?

Comment: Apologies, I see I forgot the curly braces. My own fault for not checking! Now edited.